# PRISMA - 'where' with deeply nested relation

Tags: prisma

I'm trying to use 'where' on the deeply nested relation (we can paraphrase 'on relation from relation').

Unfortunately as for 2022-06 in Prisma documentation [there is only info about using 'include' with deeply nested relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#include-deeply-nested-relations), nothing about deeply nested relations with 'where'.

Simplified types in Schema.graphql:

```
type Entity {
  id: ID!
  company: Company
}

type Company {
  id: ID!
  entity: Entity!
  status: CompanyStatus!
}

type CompanyStatus {
  id: ID!
  companies: [Company]
}
```

I want to query Entities and get only these ones, that have companies, that have exact status (let's say with status that has an ID: 1).

I've tried in multiple ways:

1)

```
function entities(parent, args, context, info) {
  const where = {
    company: { status: {id: 1} }
  }
  return context.prisma.entities.findMany({where});
}
```

Returns:

```
Unknown arg `status` in where.company.status for type CompanyRelationFilter. Did you mean `is`? Available args:\ntype CompanyRelationFilter {\n  is?: CompanyWhereInput | Null\n  isNot?: CompanyWhereInput | Null\n
```

It says to try with 'is', so here we have a try with 'is':

2)

```
function entities(parent, args, context, info) {
  const where = {
    company: { is: { status: {id: 1} } }
  }
  return context.prisma.entities.findMany({where});
}
```

Returns:

```
Unknown arg `is` in where.company.is for type CompanyWhereInput. Did you mean `id`? Available args:\ntype CompanyWhereInput {\n  AND?: CompanyWhereInput | List<CompanyWhereInput>\n  OR?: List<CompanyWhereInput>\n  NOT?: CompanyWhereInput | List<CompanyWhereInput>\n  id?: IntFilter | String\n  entity_id?: IntFilter | Int\n  entity?: EntityRelationFilter | EntityWhereInput\n  status?: CompanyStatusRelationFilter | CompanyStatusWhereInput\n  status_id?: IntFilter | Int
```

So the advice about using 'is' doesn't seem to work. It advises to use 'status' or 'status_id', which doesn't work (as in the first example).

Anyone knows whether use 'where' with deeply nested relations is possible with Prisma? If yes, how to perform it?

Answer (score 13):

A friend on mine helped me to find a solution.
You need to use double 'is':

```
function entities(parent, args, context, info) {
  const where = {
    company: { is: { status: { is {id: 1} } } }
  }
  return context.prisma.entities.findMany({where});
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I went through the same journey with the prisma documentation and this helped me connect the dots